# Wildfly RestEASY return json from plain string

Tags: json, jakarta-ee, resteasy

I have and angular app and I want to make a small session store for the case when a user has to login but should be able to resume where he left the page.

The Storing part is pretty easy since I store the received jsonstring as it is. But when I retun the value the String got escaped to be a string instead of a json. Is there a way to return a string (which is already json) as json object?

```
@Path("/session")
public class SessionStore extends Application {
    @POST
    @Path("/save/{variable}")
    @Consumes("application/json")
    public boolean save(@PathParam("variable") String var, String json) throws Exception {
        getSession().setAttribute(var, json);
        return true;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/load/{variable}")
    @Produces("application/json")
    public Object load(@PathParam("variable") String var) {
        return getSession().getAttribute(var); // this string is already a json
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you dont't want your return value to be automatically boxed into the json format, tell your JAX-RS implementation to return plain text instead of json with `@Produces("text/plain")`.

```
@GET
@Path("/load/{variable}")
@Produces("text/plain")
public String load(@PathParam("variable") String var) {
    //the cast may not be necessary, but this way your intention is clearer
    return (String) getSession().getAttribute(var);
}
```

Comment: This will also change the `Content-Type` header to `text/plain` which is not the desired behavior.

Comment: @lefloh, I intended to add that, but did'nt have time do to so nor to test my alternative solution, yet.  As the OP  needs those services for angular only, there won't be problems for now.

Comment: It's indeed no problem with angulars `$http.get` as you handle the headers on yourself. I was thinking about people using some JS-Lib with functions like `getJson` and wondering themselves why the error callback is executed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which JSON serializer you are using. I could not reproduce this behavior with Jackson.

At first I would change the return time of your method to String. As it does not make sense to convert a String to a JSON-String unless it is already a JSON-String your JSON serializer should not touch it. If it tries to be smarter you can register a custom [MessageBodyWriter](https://jax-rs-spec.java.net/nonav/2.0-rev-a/apidocs/javax/ws/rs/ext/MessageBodyWriter.html) for Strings:

```java
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class JsonStringSerializer implements MessageBodyWriter<String> {

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return type == String.class;
    }

    @Override
    public long getSize(String t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(String entity, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        entityStream.write(entity.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8")));      
    }

}
```

I'd strongly recommend **not to change the `@Produces` annotation** to `text/plain`. This may result in returning the correct content but will also change the `Content-Type` header to `text/plain`. So you are sending JSON but telling your client that it is no JSON. If the client believes you he will not parse the content any more.